# I do not know how to have a rollover effect starting from bottom , not from top of the page

Tags: html, css

Each page has a class called "current", but it has not been added to this code.

```css
Each page has a class called "current", but it has not been added to this code.

#pageNav ul,#pageNav ul li {
 

 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
 float:left;
}

#pageNav{
 background:rgba(35, 31, 32, .8);
 width:960px;
 height:60px;
}

#pageNav ul li a{
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 line-height:60px;
 width:133.3333px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:0.95em;
 text-transform:lowercase;
 
}

#pageNav ul li a:hover{
 color:rgb(251, 174, 44);
 background:none;
}

.current, #pageNav .current:hover{
 background: rgba(242, 242, 242, .4);
 color: black;
 height:40px;
 border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
 cursor: default;
 
 
}
```

```html
<header class="homeHeader pageHeader" role="banner">
<h1>Roux Academy of Art and Design<a href="/index.htm" title="home"></a></h1>
<a href="#mainContent" title="skip to main page content" class="skip">Skip to main content</a>
<nav id="pageNav" class="cf" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="programs/programs.htm" title="programs">Programs</a></li>
    <li><a href="admissions/admissions.htm" title="admissions">Admissions</a></li>
    <li><a href="student_portal.htm" title="student portal">Student Portal</a></li>
    <li><a href="campus_portal.htm" title="campus portal">Campus</a></li>
    <li><a href="alumni/alumni.htm" title="alumni">Alumni</a></li>
    <li><a href="about/about.htm"  title="about Roux Academy">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: For the last CSS code, I want to have a current tab with the height of 40 px STARTING FROM BOTTOM. However, it does not happen :( and it starts from top of the page to add height.

Comment: there is no current class in the html you have provided in the snippet, so maybe you havent added it by mistake? If thats not the case update your snippet so we can see it.